# Route traffic to specific node pool in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Say there are two node pools A and B in a Kubernetes cluster and both the node pools are running service named service1.
Is it possible to configure ingress route such that a request to service1 get routed to service1 running in either pool A or pool B based on custom header in the request?
If no, are there any other alternatives to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify, which exactly ingress do you want to use (on which platform). Here is an example to nginx ingress controller: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-headers/

Comment: nginx ingress. How can the routing be done to specific node pool services based on header value?

Comment: Maybe some [annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#annotations) will help you? Look [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary) for `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header-value`. When the request header is set to this value, it will be routed to the canary.